# How to place a scroll down button in the middle of split screen window?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The split screen is similar to this one here: http://codepen.io/rileyjshaw/pen/vGLvVo

I'm trying to place a scroll down button on it. How can I place this button in the center and on the bottom side of the window?

HTML:

```
.half
    p These panes always split the window in the correct direction.
.half
    p
        | Pure CSS, only 5 rules.
        span.social
            | by  
            a[target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/rileyjshaw'] rileyjshaw
            |.
```

CSS:

```
// Maximum aspect ratio beforem switching to a vertical split.
$ASPECT_W: 4
$ASPECT_H: 3

// All you need, right here:
body
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap

.half
    width: 100%
    flex-basis: $ASPECT_W / ($ASPECT_W + $ASPECT_H) * 100vh
    flex-grow: 1

// Good night, and good luck.

















// Doop, de boop boop...





















// Unrelated visual styles:
html, body
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    margin: 0

.half
    position: relative
    font: 600 32px Poppins, sans-serif
    color: #f6e8ea
    background: #ef626c
    + .half
        background: #84dcff

p
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    width: 72%
    margin: 0
    text-align: center

.social
    display: block
    max-height: 0
    opacity: 0
    animation: appear 1s 4s

a
    color: #f9eef0

@keyframes appear
    50%
        max-height: 2em
        opacity: 0
    100%
        max-height: 2em


opacity: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your problem would be to create a div with an absolute position. You could then align it to the center and to the bottom. Here some example HTML and CSS I created using the example codepen: http://codepen.io/tcaer/pen/xOpjBB

HTML:

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 bottom: 100px;
```

If you require to use `position: absolute` inside another div, just put `position: relative` on the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to put a scroll_down Icon in middle of Screen and also must scroll down to next section when clicked.

CSS:

```
scrolldown{
    position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        left: 45%;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        bottom: 0%;

    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="scrolldown">
  <a href="#sectionId"><img src="images/scroll_down_homepage.gif" /></a>
</div>

<section id="sectionId">
//Content
</section>
```